# Neo4j: Usage of parameters of type list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

List parameters cannot be indexed in neo4j 4. Whenever you try to take an element from a parameter of type list, this error is thrown:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
Did not find any type information for expression ContainerIndex(Parameter(r,Any),SignedDecimalIntegerLiteral(0))
```

Neo4j Version: 4.0.3

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

DB Mode: Causal Cluster

An example query to reproduce the issue is:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE ($range[0] > user.id OR user.id > $range[1])
return user
limit 1
```

`$range` is the parameter in question with an example value `[100, 200]`

This error does not happen in the previous neo4j version 3.5, as we are currently migrating to neo4j 4. It happens in the neo4j browser, and through drivers. I currently use python driver 1.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is indeed a problem with neo4j 4, and I am glad to see that you have already submitted an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12505) for that.

I have found 2 workarounds (but hopefully the issue will be fixed soon):

1. Explicitly convert the list values to the right type. For example, if the `id` values are integers:

   ```
   MATCH (user:User)
   WHERE TOINTEGER($range[0]) > user.id OR user.id > TOINTEGER($range[1])
   RETURN user
   LIMIT 1
   ```
2. Assign the list values to variables and use the variables instead:

   ```
   WITH $range[0] AS upper, $range[1] AS lower
   MATCH (user:User)
   WHERE upper > user.id OR user.id > lower
   RETURN user
   LIMIT 1
   ```

Comment: These two workarounds did work. Thank you, and wish it will be resolved soon. AIso, it can be solved by passing a map from the python code. {lower: 100, upper: 200}.